# Algorithm for searching unique elements combinations in C (elements position in resulting string doesn't matter)

Tags: c, algorithm

I have code for char array unique elements searching. But it works incorrectly. For example, in case of "ABCD" array, I lose "ABD" case. How can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void     fun(char *str, int size, int depth)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i < size - depth + 1)
    {
        j = i + 1;
        while (j < size - depth + 2)
        {
            printf("%c", str[i]);
            k = j;
            while (k < j + depth - 1)
            {
                printf("%c", str[k]);
                k++;
            }
            printf("\n");
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int     main(void)
{
    char    *str = "ABCD";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(str))
    {
        fun(str, strlen(str), i + 1);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The result is: A A A A B B B C C D AB AC AD BC BD CD ABC ACD BCD ABCD

And I need: A B C D AB AC AD BC BD CD ABC **ABD** ACD BCD ABCD

So as you can see there are several bugs - repeats of single chars at the beginning and missing ABD case. If the string is "ABCDE" there are more variants will be missing.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Well you can think of me as rubber duck and try to edit the question with what each of your line is supposed to do.

Comment: @alk [Kinda like rush commenting.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6582958#6582958)

Comment: You're looking at a recursion problem to find all possible substrings. You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-print-substrings-given-string/).

Comment: @CarolChen thanks, but this solution doesn't cover all necessary cases.

Comment: Do you know about for-loops? Because each of your while-loops does exactly what for-loops were made to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should fix the problem:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(char *str, char *data, int start, int end, int idx, int depth)
{
    if (idx == depth)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++)
            printf("%c", data[j]);
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= depth - idx; i++)
    {
        data[idx] = str[i];
        fun(str, data, i + 1, end, idx + 1, depth);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "ABCD";
    int i = 0;

    while (i < strlen(str))
    {
        char data[i + 1];
        fun(str, data, 0, strlen(str) - 1, 0, i + 1);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Output:

A
B
C
D
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
ABC
**ABD**
ACD
BCD
ABCD

And also works for "ABCDE" and etc.

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly useful answer as it doesn't help anyone understand why the original code wasn't working.

Comment: @DavidZ it is hard to fix solution with 3 nested loops and it was easier for me to implement in this way:)

Comment: @DavidZ thank you for your worry, but this code solved my problem. I'm satisfied with MrBlack fast answer.

Comment: @SergiyShilingov Sure, I'm not saying the code isn't useful for you; I'm saying it's not useful for anyone else. A good answer is useful both to the person who asked the question and to other people who come along with similar problems in the future. And MrBlack: of course it may have been easier for you to post this kind of answer. There's nothing wrong with you posting it. All I'm saying is that I don't think it's a good answer, for the reasons I've explained.